# NRPE-like checks from windows-based machines

Tags: windows, monitoring, nagios, nrpe

I am sorry for not being able to come up with a more descriptive question title.

For getting remote metrics I use nrpe on linux-based machines and [nsclient++](http://nsclient.org/nscp/) on windows-based machines.

If I need to check, for example, if a certain server is reachable *from another server*, I'd just run an appropriate plugin (like check_http) using nrpe. I've recently faced the need to do the same thing, but the remote server is running windows so I am stuck with nsclient++.

Now, you can run scripts from nsclient++, so you can write a vb/powershell script, that will do that. Before I do that, however, I'd like to know if there are any existing solutions (surely, I am not the only person on Earth who had to deal with this).

At the very least I'd like to have something, like check_http, that I will able to run using nsclient++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should be, what you are looking for:
http://www.nagioswiki.com/wiki/index.php/Using_NSclient_and_NagiosPluginsNT_for_Service_Delivery

It is a combination of nagios plugins for windows and nsclient++.

Comment: I really don't know how I've missed it! I'll give it a shot, of course

Comment: Oh well, I might as well accept this answer. I've checked the plugins, that you've found, but, really, they are terrible. Sure, they seem to do what they are supposed to do, but the functionality is extremely limited. It seems, that the author was just lazy. I guess, I will have to implement it myself.

Comment: perhaps the script you are searching for is available in perl and will also run on windows. have you tried NagiosExchange (http://exchange.nagios.org/) or MonitorExchange (http://www.monitoringexchange.org/)?

Comment: just for the record, there are no plugins, that implement at least the most basic subset of the functionality of check_http, neither at exchange.nagios.org, nor at monitoringexchange.org. I've written my own using powershell.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to turn the Windows server into *nix with cygwin, run an ssh server on the Windows machine, and then use check_by_ssh :-)

Comment: Kyle Brandt♦
Could you tell me more about this way?

Answer (score 0):

Just as you can run the NRPE/NSclient checks locally, you can use psexec to run them from a remote machine.